# Find a sequence of integers which give max in each step

Tags: functions, integer-sequence

I would like to write a program in *Mathematica* to look for the integer $n$ such that the following definition holds for any $1 < m < n $

$$\frac{f(n)}{f(m)}>1+\frac{\log(n/m)}{\log(n) \log(\log(m))}$$

where $f(n)$ is for example number of divisors of $n$ (and also count the number of resulting sets).

I wrote the following code, but the problem is that when it finds the first `j1` in the next step of the `For`, it looks for the value `j2` for which

$$\frac{f(j_2)}{f(j_1)}>1+\frac{\log(j_2/j_1)}{\log(j_2) \log(\log( j_1))}$$

but I want it to find the `j2` such that

$$\forall j,\ j_1 \le j < j_2 \implies \frac{f(j_2)}{f(j)}>1+\frac{\log(j_2/j)}{\log (j_2) \log(\log(j))}$$

**Note**: In the following example `k[*]` is a special and known sub sequence of integers.

```
i = 20;

count = 0;

list = {i};

For[j = i, j <= 100, j++,

    If[ f[k[j]]/f[k[i]] > 1 + Log[k[j]/k[i]]/(Log[k[j]] Log[Log[k[i]]]), i = j; 
        AppendTo[list, i];
        count = count + 1
    ]
];

list

Print["count= ", count]
```

Comment: Have you seen `DivisorSigma[]` already?

Comment: @ J. M.♦, yes, but my problem is:    assume we start with k[20], then when we reach to the first k[j] such that not only f[k[j]]/f[k[20]]>(1+Log[k[j]/k[20]]/(Log[k[j]]Log[Log[k[20]]])), also f[k[j]]/f[k[i]]>(1+Log[k[j]/k[i]]/(Log[k[j]]Log[Log[k[i]]])), for all i such that 20<i<j.

Comment: Could you give an example for `f` and `k` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks, for example f[n_]:=DivisorSigma[1,n]/n and k=Table[s[i],{i,20,100}] is a subsequence of superabundant or highly composite numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for the original question (without the k..)

```
Last@Last@
  Reap[ Do[If[ 
     And @@ Table[ 
        f[n]/f[m] > 1 + Log[n/m]/(Log[n] Log[Log[m]]) ,
                {m, 2, n - 1}] , Sow[n]] , {n, 3, 100}] ]
```

If you want to use explicit loops you need an outer n loop and inner m loop.

```
Last@Last@Reap[ Do[
        m = 2;
        While[m < n &&   f[n]/f[m] > 1 + Log[n/m]/(Log[n] Log[Log[m]]) , ++m] ;
        If[ m == n, Sow[n]];, {n, 3, 100}] ]
```